# Use of Custom Object to authenticate Users

Tags: custom-object, force.com-sites, user

We have public website built with Salesforce.  Public(guest) users can view the images and short description of products. To view price, they need to register and login to website.

So, for this if we create an custom object called "Site Users" and when click on "View Price", if we authenticate those users by "Site Users", is it recommended?

My intention to this question is, couple of years back I read that it is not legal to create your own user authentication in Salesforce. We must use Salesforce authentication for site users as well.

I am searching that link, but I am not able to find similar article.
If someone has idea on this, please provide some feedback/suggestion.

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish Shukla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Salesforce.com Master Subscription Agreement](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf)

> 4.4 Usage Restrictions. You *will not* (a) *make* any Service or Content *available* to, or use any Service or Content for the benefit of, *anyone other
>   than You or Users*, (b) sell, resell, license, sublicense, distribute, rent or lease any Service or Content, or include any Service or Content in a service bureau or outsourcing offering, ...

(Emphasis mine)

Here, a User is defined as:

> “User” means an individual who is authorized by You to use a Service, for whom You have ordered the Service, and to whom You (or We at Your request) have supplied a user identification and password. ...

In other words, you can't make your own user identification scheme. You have to use what you're given. And in this case, you probably mean to use either Community or Customer Portal licenses (or something similar).

Also, it's generally a *bad idea* to implement your own authentication. It also means you have to invent an entire security model (profile, sharing access, etc). Using the built-in licenses gives you greater point-and-click control on who can see and edit records, fields, and so on.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks a lot for providing the master agreement link and your suggestion on authentication system.